# ASP.NET Web API login with Facebook & Twitter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, twitter, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm going to be diving into ASP.NET Web API and would like to know if there is an easy way to have my users login with Facebook and Twitter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the new release of Visual Studio 2012 and .NEt 4.5 Microsoft has gone full on with OAuth/OpenID.

[Article with examples on how to support Facebook, Twitter, and Google accounts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/15/oauth-openid-support-for-webforms-mvc-and-webpages.aspx)
(there are 3 more blog articles linked at the bottom).

And [here's a sweet little video](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/videos/oauth-in-the-default-aspnet-45-templates) from S. Hanselmann no less.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely have a look at **[DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)**. It's an open source library for .Net which supports OpenID, OAuth v1/v2 and InfoCards. There's some nice documentation and sample code on the site as well as in various blogs (such at **[this one](http://jgb146.blogspot.com/2012/02/dotnetopenauth-twitter.html)**) that should get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

As for Facebook:
They have a lot of documentation on implementing logging in with Facebook Accounts.
Facebook Login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

They have a JavaScript SDK too: (Can't add link due to reputation restrictions, but check on the SDK References Link)

Finally, you could also try a 3rd party API for .net.
There are several. Here is one: http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/developing-with-facebook-api-sdk-w-asp.net

I haven't tried it, but it's Open Source so if you don't want to use it, you can check the code and learn how to implement it on your own.